# C - Can't add to or call specific array?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, range

My program takes two parameters eg "./a abc xyz" where all a's in a text file are replaced with x's and b's with y's and so on. When given a range, eg. A-C, it reads it as ABC.
The issue I am having is that when I add chars to a certain array(alphaRange2) I get a segmentation fault when I run it. I use the same code for array alphaRange1, which does accept the chars as shown when I print alphaRange1 in a for loop. When I try to print alphaRange2, no values are printed. 
Here's my code:

```
int translate(char set1[], char set2[]) {
    int c;
    char ch;
    char ch2;
    int dash1 = 0;
    int dash2 = 0;
    int previous = -1;
    int next;
    char alphaRange1[MAXSIZE];
    char alphaRange2[MAXSIZE];
    size_t i;
    int j = 0;
    int k;
    int l;
    for (i=0; i <= strlen(set1); i++) {
        if (set1[i] == '-') {
            for (ch = set1[i-1]; ch <= set1[i+1]; ch++) {
                alphaRange1[k] = ch;
                k++;
            }
        }   
    }
    for (i=0; i <= strlen(set2); i++) {
        if (set2[i] == '-') {
            for (ch = set2[i-1]; ch <= set2[i+1]; ch++) {
                alphaRange2[l] = ch;
                l++;
            }
        }   
    }
    /*for (i=0; alphaRange1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%c", alphaRange1[i]);
    }*/

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((dash1 == 1) && (dash2 == 1)) {
            for (i=0; alphaRange1[i] != '\0' || alphaRange2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                if (c == alphaRange1[i]) {
                    c = alphaRange2[i];
                }
            }
        } else if ((dash1 == 0) && (dash2 == 0)) {
            for (i=0; i <= strlen(set1) || i <= strlen(set2); i++) {
                if (c == set1[i]) {
                    c = set2[i];
                    if ((c == set1[1]) && (set1[1] == set2[0])) {
                        c = set2[0];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

        if (previous > -1) {
            putchar(previous);
        }
        previous = c;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j, k;
    char set1[MAXSIZE];
    char set2[MAXSIZE];
    char ch;
    char alphaRange1[MAXSIZE];
    for (i=0; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j=0; argv[1][j] != '\0' || argv[2][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            set1[i] = argv[1][i];
            set2[i] = argv[2][i];
        }
    }
    /*for (i=0; i <= strlen(set1); i++) {
        if (set1[i] == '-') {
            for (ch = set1[i-1]; ch <= set1[i+1]; ch++) {
                alphaRange1[k] = ch;
                k++;
            }
        }   
    }
    for (i=0; alphaRange1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%c", alphaRange1[i]);
    }*/
    translate(set1, set2);
    return 1;
}
```

The code runs if you take out anything including alphaRange2, and I've been testing it using commented out print loop, which works if you comment out the entire while loop. How do I make this work?
Thanks.

Comment: Turn on the compiler's warnings.

Comment: For a start: k and l seem to be uninitialised when used, thus you get undefined behaviour. Also note that k and l aren't what I'd call *descriptive* names.

Comment: Also at main for-loops  are wrong.

Comment: I don't think accessing `set1[strlen(set1)+1]` is a good idea because it may be out-of-range or uninitialized and accessing such area will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: for (i = 0; i <= strlen(x); i++) - strlen together with "<=" in a for loop is nearly always wrong. It should be "<"

Comment: The first loop beggining with `for (i=0; i < argc; i++)` in the `main()` function seems wrong. Why not just use `strcpy(set1, argv[1]); strcpy(set2, argv[2]);`? Also don't forget to check the number of arguments before accessing arguments.

Comment: before accessing anything beyond `argv[0]`, always check `argc` to assure that such a parameter exists.  The posted code seems to be expecting two command line parameters.  so argc should be 3.  So if it is not 3, then output a 'usage' message to stderr (probably using `fprintf()` and then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

Comment: what happens if the two command line parameters are not the same length?  then the `setx[]` will receive trash, AND the code will be accessing memory beyond the upper bound of the associated argv[] array.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  You might want to use two calls to `strcpy()` to copy those parameters.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`.

Comment: the process of translating code (there is the function `tr` available) is for each char in the original array (set1) to be replaced with the same offset char in the translate array (set2)  However, that is not a valid translation.  the a translate operation for characters, needs to have two arrays: 1) all the available characters to be translated, 2) all the translated characters (at the same offset) in a second array.  Then repeated characters, etc are easily handled. and the function is fed with the un-translated array

Comment: for the posted code, just copy the second array over the first array. a very simple call to `strcpy()`